# Asp.Net Global.asax access to the current requested Page object

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

Is there any way i can access the page object from within the global.asax Application_EndRequest function ?

I'm trying to set the text of a label at the end of the request but accessing the page is proving to be more difficult than I thought.

here is what i have that's currently NOT working:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        Context.Items.Add("Request_Start_Time", DateTime.Now);

    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TimeSpan tsDuration = DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)Context.Items["Request_Start_Time"]);

        System.Web.UI.Page page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
            Label label = page.FindControl("lblProcessingTime") as Label;
            if (label != null)
            {
                label.Text = String.Format("Request Processing Time: {0}", tsDuration.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

page is always null here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably best just to create a BasePage class from which all your pages should inherit. Then you can put the code within the Unload event of the page and there will be no issue.

Comment: This is actually a good idea.  It does require a tweak to the design, but it doesn't warrant a negative vote, IMO.

Comment: Thanks. I just thought it would be helpful to point out another approach, which may not have been noticed.

Comment: Good call Nolodorin.  I'd think this would be the best idea. Even better would be a master page to make sure the label would always be there as it sounds like every page would have the same label.

Comment: I'll check out this method, the label is on a masterpage and i do have a basepage already defined.  the only problem is there is more than one basepage defined so i'll have to do it for each.

Comment: That's fine - just put the event handler setup in the constructor of the MasterPage. i.e. this.Page.Unload += ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in Application_Start and Application_End.

From MSDN:

The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

Comment: this isnt the Application_Start or Application_End, it's Application_StartRequest and Application_EndRequest.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage of the request's life cycle the page has already been rendered and the page object is not available anymore. You would need to use an earlier event.

That said, I wouldn't recommend this approach as there are a number of issues with it:

You are using FindControl. This code will break if the name of the control changes.

This code will get run for any request, not just pages and not just the particular pages you need this to run for.

This code should be in a master page or a page base class where you can access the label in a type safe manner.

Comment: FindControl wont break if not found, the label will just be null.

Comment: Yes the label will be null, the functionality will break. I abhor the use of FindControl. In 99% of the cases it is used it is due to poor design. There will almost always be a way to declare a strongly typed instance of the control you are trying to find.